# A strange .net concept where we can't use observer pattern or delegates

Tags: c#, .net

i had attended an interview where interviewer asked a question where i failed to answer.The question is i have five classes A,B,C,D,E .The requirement is If A changes C and D should reflect the same changes, but A doesn't know who is C and D and vice versa .Same way if B changes E also should change but they don't know each other.
I started with observer pattern but he doesn't agree and he is telling for that sender and recipient should know.Then i started with delegates that also he is telling they should know each other and i failed to answer and forgot to ask the answer from him finally:)

Any body has any idea about this questions answer?

Comment: sounds like a pattern, like MVVM - DataBinding..

Comment: I think that is a kind of lame interview question. Way too specific and not a good assessment of whether the answerer will be a good employee. I think that there are a great many fine developers who are poor interviewers.

Comment: I don't know, I think it is a good question for a WPF / SilverLight / MVC developer position. To me the question reflects critical thinking and a base knowledge of Databinding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for a variant of the [Mediator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) called the [Publish-Subscribe pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern).  Basically, you would be introducing a new class `M` which all of your classes (`A` through `E`) would have to know about.  Then each of your classes could tell `M` which events they were interested in consuming / producing and `M` would route the events to each class appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to answer this without knowing more of the actual requirements.
One way is to use some sort of messaging system where one class will push a message (a shared object) that other classes can react to.

One implementation of this is NServiceBus and message queuing.

Another view of the problem could be that if all your classes implement interfaces, you are abstracting the implementation from the contract, which means the classes don't have direct knowledge of each other. They only know about the contract(promise) of each class, but the implementer could be arbitrary/changing.

Answer (score 0):

My Immediate thought was MVVM say A is view, View is updated. Though DataBinding it updates the ViewModel which could be C, In turn C could update the source of D or vise versa D->C->A.  That's how I understood the question.